# 503 error trying to enqueue custom jQuery script in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to set up my very first custom WordPress theme. I am using "front-page.php" to set up a standard landing page, and am trying to use a few jQuery files (all of which are written in compatibility mode). When the functions.php file is written to where I expect it to work, it gives me a 503 error, and the site only works with code I know isn't correct.

I have tried enqueuing vs registering, adding admin code, de-activating and re-registering jquery, and adding all the "add_action"s into one line. What am I missing? No JS of any sort has yet worked on this theme. Here is the functions.php file:

```
<?php

add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

function modify_jquery() {
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery-custom', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.3', 'true');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-custom');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'modify_jquery' );

function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'navbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/navbar.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fixedheader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/fixedheader.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skills', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/skills.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );

function theme_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'navbar', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/scripts/navbar.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fixedheader', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/scripts/fixedheader.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skills', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/scripts/skills.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_admin_scripts' );

function register_navigation() {
    $args = array(
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>' );

  register_navigation($args);
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_navigation' );

?>
```

I would like for my site to have a navigation menu that comes down as the reader scrolls down (this worked in a static page before I made it a wordpress theme file), among some other jQuery functionality. The rest of the site works fine, pictures load, etc. but I have not been able to add any script successfully. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay for start you don't need to do re-register jQuery script. The one available by default should work.

Also the registration on `admin_enqueue_scripts` is a bit confusing form me as this would register script on dashboard side and the `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` is useful if you are registering scripts from inside a plugin.

Considering that you have the default jQuery file and the handle isn't de registered, the following code should work for you.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('theme-navbar', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/navbar.js', array('jquery), $ver = false, $in_footer = true );
}
```

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri() //points to the directory in your active theme where stylesheet is located so the path will be something like '/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME'`
Just make sure that your scripts path are correct and this should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back! Unfortunately when I plug that code in it still gives me a 503 error... my suspicion is something is not configured right in my WP instance or my host can't handle it for some reason, could either of those be true?

Comment: There is a good chance that your server setup is messed up. Try contacting your hosting provider support system. If all else fails you can always use script tag in footer to enqueue your scripts. Admittedly this is not the ideal solution but it does work. Just make sure you add script tag after `wp_footer` function